# Safari rendering Fontawesome with transparent padding

Tags: safari, icons, alignment, render, font-awesome

I'm using Font-awesome in my project, and every icon is aligned in the middle of the line. On Chrome, Firefox and IE, They are aligned corretly, but on Safari, the icon drop around 3 or 4 pixels.

I inspect the icon and in every browser, they are render and ocupate the exactly space they should be. But in Safari, they are rendered with extra top size, a transparent padding on top of the icon. It's not vertical-alignment or line-height problem, the character itself have this "transparent padding" on top.

That seens silly, but on a huge project, every icon is aligned 3/4px down than it should be give me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that you have a different default line height in the different browsers. Try explicitly setting this to see if if it makes a difference:

**CSS**

```
i{
line-height:20px;
}
```

or even

```
i{
display:inline-block;
}
```

depending on the specifics of your styling, you might need to also set a class on the i tag, e.g.

```
i.icon-class{ ....}
```

Good luck!